# How to remove all characters within a string after a non-alphanumerical character

Tags: python

I want to remove all the character after a non-alphanumerical character ('_') within a string.
For example:

```
Petr_;Y -> Petr 
ČEZ_^(České_energetické_závody) -> ČEZ
```

I tried:

```
''.join(c for c in mystring if c.isalnum())
```

But this way I'm stripping off only alphanumerical characters itself.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: An efficient way is you can use re module in python to achieve this, 

  

    >>> from re import split
    >>> s1 = "ČEZ_^(České_energetické_závody)"
    >>> split('_', s1)[0]
    'ČEZ'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the `.split()` method on strings.

```
new_string = your_string.split('_',1)[0]
```

This way you keep only what's before the fisrt '_'.

Answer (score 1):

Searching the index of first occurrence of "_" will do:

```
s1 = "Petr_;Y"  
s2 = "ČEZ_^(České_energetické_závody)"

s11 = s1[:s1.index("_")]
s22 = s2[:s2.index("_")]
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will produce an `ValueError` if there is no `_` in the input string.

Comment: I agree with that, but since "_" seemed to be given here, I preferred to focus on detecting it.